# How do I retrieve related objects through many-to-many join table in parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have 3 tables, User, Book and Vote.  A user can vote a book up or down.  I am trying to retrieve all the books the user has not voted on.

I'm trying to use

```
var voteQuery = PFQuery(className:"Vote")
voteQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

var bookQuery = PFQuery(className:"Book")
bookQuery.whereKey("books", doesNotMatchKey:"book", inQuery:voteQuery)

bookQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (books: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        print("Successfully retrieved \(books!.count) books.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let books = books {
            print("books")
            print(books)
            for book in books {
                print(book.objectId)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

This is returning all books, without omitting books that the user has voted on.  Conversely, I get no results if I use

```
bookQuery.whereKey("books", matchesKey:"book", inQuery:voteQuery)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

User:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "bcryptPassword": "xx",
        "createdAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.023Z",
        "email": "email@example.com",
        "objectId": "9uoWak96sp",
        "phone": "415-392-0202",
        "sessionToken": "xx",
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.023Z",
        "username": "myUsername"
    }
] }
```

Book:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.510Z",
        "objectId": "3rKWI2qI0b",
        "title": "Book B",
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.510Z"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.383Z",
        "objectId": "zsEhE9QCMU",
        "title": "Book A",
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.383Z"
    }
] }
```

Vote:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "book": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Book",
            "objectId": "zsEhE9QCMU"
        },
        "createdAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.647Z",
        "objectId": "gfIRXbPtyf",
        "upVote": true,
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-17T20:15:42.647Z",
        "user": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "9uoWak96sp"
        }
    }
] }
```

Comment: what is books? As i can see in your parse classes you dont have key called `books`

Comment: Hi @adolfosrs, thanks for looking.  I'm not sure what should go there, so far i've tried 

bookQuery.whereKey("books", matchesKey:"book", inQuery:voteQuery),
bookQuery.whereKey("objectId", matchesKey:"book", inQuery:voteQuery),
bookQuery.whereKey("book", matchesKey:"book", inQuery:voteQuery)

and all are returning an empty array.